# Angular 6: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RoleGuardService]

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-guards

I want to use RoleGuard service in one of my Angular 6 project. I have created a file - '`role-guard.service.ts`' under "`_guards`" folder. Now in the routes file, I have declared the same as below and try to implement the same. Please note, I have a shared module and I did not declare the roleguardservice within the export.

```
import { RoleGuardService } from '../../_guards/role-guard.service';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'edit-account-info', component: EditAccountInfoComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuardService] },
    ....
    ....
    ]
}
```

Below is my `app.module.ts file`:

```
import { AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard} from '../../_guards/auth.guard';
....
....
exports : [
    // 
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard, {
    provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
    useValue: {
      siteKey: environment.recaptchasiteKey,
    } as RecaptchaSettings,
  }]
```

I want to change the routes depends on user roles. 
Like, if user role type 1, then he will redirect to "edit-account-info" otherwise (if user role type 2) he will redirect to "agent/edit-account-info". If user role type 2 wants to access the path "edit-account-info" he will go to "unauthorize" page.

But to implement it, when I want to access the page "edit-account-info" it shows me the error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RoleGuardService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RoleGuardService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for RoleGuardService!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RoleGuardService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RoleGuardService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for RoleGuardService! ... ....

Below is the `role-guard.sevice.ts` file content:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
//import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { CommonService } from './../services/common.service';
import { AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard} from './auth.guard';

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuardService implements CanActivate {
  private userDetails: any;
  public user_salt: any;
  public roleName: any;

  constructor(
    //public auth: AuthService, 
    public router: Router,
    private commService: CommonService,
    private location: Location,
    ) {

    }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    this.userDetails = this.commService.getSession('user');
    this.user_salt = this.commService.getSession('user_salt');
    const resultStorage = JSON.parse(this.commService.localstorageDecryption(this.userDetails, this.user_salt, 'N'));

    if (this.roleName === resultStorage.type) {
      return true;
    }

    // navigate to not found page
    this.router.navigate(['/404']);
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Add `RoleGuardService` to your `providers`?

Comment: I think so, but how can I add the same? E.g. providers: [AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard, RoleGuardService, { ... ??

Comment: is `RoleGuardService` part of the app module or the shared module?

Comment: as I have added the user.guard in the app module and it works fine, hence I think roleguard should be the part of app.module.ts file.

Comment: if it's part of the app module, add it to the providers array `providers: [AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard, RoleGuardService, ...]`

Comment: I added the same but when I want to access the "edit-account-info", it shows me another error > Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RoleGuardService -> Location]: .... .....

Comment: the new error looks like it has to do in an injection in the RoleGuardService, can you post code for that?

Comment: I have modified my question and you can see the content of role-guard.service.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error is caused by not adding the `RoleGuardService` to your `providers`.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard, RoleGuardService, {
    provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
    useValue: {
      siteKey: environment.recaptchasiteKey,
    } as RecaptchaSettings,
  }]
  ...
})
```

The subsequent error has to do with an injection in your `RoleGuardService`.  You have `private location: Location` in your `constructor` but no import statement for Angular's Location.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have to `import` service and `Location` in your `app.module.ts` and add it in `providers` array like below.

```
   import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
   import { RoleGuardService } from '../../_guards/role-guard.service';     
   import { AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard} from '../../_guards/auth.guard';
    ....
    ....
    exports : [
        // 
      ],
      providers: [AuthGuard, RoleGuardService, 
        Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
        DisableAuthGuard, {
        provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
        useValue: {
          siteKey: environment.recaptchasiteKey,
        } as RecaptchaSettings,
      }]
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I added the same but when I want to access the "edit-account-info", it shows me another error > Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RoleGuardService -> Location]:

Comment: have you declared your service as injectable with in @Injectable() decorator

Comment: I have modified my question and you can see the content of role-guard.service.ts

Comment: Now got your issue you also need to provide Location in provider array

Comment: Yes, I added `import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common'; ` and it works.

Comment: I have updated answer with Location. glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **RoleGuardService**  in app.module.ts

here is the example:

```
import { AuthGuard, DisableAuthGuard} from '../../_guards/auth.guard';
@NgModule({
providers: [ 
...
RoleGuardService
],
imports: [ 
...
]
}
})
```

Comment: I added the same but when I want to access the "edit-account-info", it shows me another error > Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RoleGuardService -> Location]:

Answer (score 0):

As per the answers above, list `RoleGuardService` under *providers*,
and if this service is provided from another module, and you want to use it in AppModule, make sure to import that module in AppModule as well.